# Ember JS performance problems

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working on a benchmark research between change detection mechanisms in JavaScript frameworks. I am comparing Virtual DOM and KVO. For KVO example I have chosen Ember and I have developed a little demo app with a tweet list.

Referring to the dev talk 2014 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DX3vJiqxm4&feature=youtu.be&t=1673) as I understand - KVO is supposed to be faster at changing one list element when there is a big amount displayed(I think even when all of the elements are changed), but for the application I have developed with these differrent implementations(React, Ember) the Ember app is significantly(alot of times) slower than the React app at changing one list item when there are 1000 displayed.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nLqr2w/17/) of my developed app. The tweets are sorted by favorites and they have to get sorted on every change of favorites in the model. If you take a look at the fiddle you have to press SHOW LIST for the list and buttons for changing tweets to get displayed(takes a few seconds to show up).

```
    App.AppModel = Ember.Object.extend({
    topTweets: function() {
        return this.get('tweets').sort(function(a, b) {
            return b.favorites - a.favorites;
        })/*.slice(0,10)*/;
    }.property('tweets.@each.favorites')
});
App.appModel = App.AppModel.create({
    tweets: renderTweets()
});
```

This is the model that listens to changes of favorites.

```
changeOneTweet:function(){
                        var iPosition = _.random(0, numTweets - 1);
                var iFavorites = _.random(0, 4000);
                App.appModel.get('tweets').set(iPosition + '.favorites', iFavorites);

                    },
```

This is the function that changes one "tweet".

I hope that Ember experts here can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You use the debug version of emberjs, which contains debug code. Use the prod version for performance testing. Also know, that ember has a totally different render model now: The new glimmer engine.

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Comment: Does the fact that it has glimmer engine means Ember is no longer an option for a KVO example? As I read [here](https://auth0.com/blog/face-off-virtual-dom-vs-incremental-dom-vs-glimmer/) - Glimmer works similar to virtual DOM?

Comment: Basically its much more complex. It's using the options of KVO to only update the required parts, but also using other concepts. It's capable to use virtual DOM techniques, but also knows what parts of the DOM are static and what are dynamic. Also know for performance tests that the amount of static code is highly relevant, and initial render performance is not rerender performance.

Comment: Thank you! What other frameworks/libraries are out there that use KVO?

Answer (score 1):

Ember now uses <s>HTMLBars</s> (edit: which was eclipsed by Glimmer -- a fork of HTMLBars) and not the Handlebars templating language.  I'd use something like ember-twiddle to mock up your app, as I am unaware of a way to use ES6 syntax in jsfiddle.

I don't know if you intended to use Handlebars or HTMLBars, but the ember-template-compiler states it requires version 2.0 or higher of Handlebars as well.  With that said, Handlebars has some known performance issues with large lists (see here: https://colintoh.com/blog/htmlbars).

A lot has changed since pre-2.0 Ember.  Here's a random ember-twiddle I found as an example that might help you along in the right direction: https://ember-twiddle.com/fc4760a5e5c475bbabc1